# Adding more than one relative layout to the linear layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view

How to add more than one relative layout to the linear layout programmatically .
I tried but it gives me this exception "Specified child already has a parent. You must call removeview()"
Here is my code,

```
  RelativeLayout addlangmid = new RelativeLayout(mActivity);
                addlangmid.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.language_bg_top);
                TextView langname = new TextView(mActivity);
                LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.setMargins(20, 0, 30, 30);
                langname.setText(str[0]);
                addlangmid.addView(langname, params);

                fulllay.addView(addlangmid, 0);


                RelativeLayout addlangmid1 = new RelativeLayout(mActivity);
                addlangmid.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.language_bg_middle);
                TextView langname1 = new TextView(mActivity);
                LayoutParams params1 = new LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params1.setMargins(20, 0, 30, 30);
                langname1.setText(str[0]);
                addlangmid1.addView(langname, params1);

                fulllay.addView(addlangmid1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the below line

```
addlangmid1.addView(langname, params1);
```

to

```
addlangmid1.addView(langname1, params1);
```

You are adding langname to addlangmid and addlangmid1. Hence the error is coming.

Comment: Also change : 
                addlangmid.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.language_bg_middle);
              to                                            
                addlangmid1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.language_bg_middle);

Comment: Ya! it is working fine now,thank you so much...Kameswari and Ashwini